# Something went wrong, Android Studio + Volley

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

i'm very beginner in this problem.
i following the tutorials from youtube make a database for user register, i use localhost and put the php file into htdocs and it's succes but when i tried to put the php file into 000webhost file manager. the result is 'something went wrong' it should be 'Succesfully Registered'. i dont know what should i do because there's no error in logcat. i'm sure there's no error in php file because i've matched it with the real source code.
[Example Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qknmi.png)

Thank you in advance.

here is my code

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText etName, etEmail, etPassword, etReenterPassword;
    private TextView tvStatus;
    private String URL = "https://db4image.000webhostapp.com/login/register.php";
    private String name, email, password, reenterPassword;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        etName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        etReenterPassword = findViewById(R.id.repass);
        tvStatus = findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        name = email = password = reenterPassword = "";
    }

    public void daftarCok (View view) {
        name = etName.getText().toString().trim();
        email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        reenterPassword = etReenterPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        if(!password.equals(reenterPassword)){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Password Mismatch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else if(!name.equals("") && !email.equals("") && !password.equals("")){
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("success")) {
                        tvStatus.setText("Successfully registered.");
                        Intent inten = new Intent(Register.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(inten);
                    }
                    else if (response.equals("failure")) {
                        tvStatus.setText("Something went wrong!");
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                    data.put("name", name);
                    data.put("email", email);
                    data.put("password", password);
                    return data;
                }
            };
            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }
    }

    public void login(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is my register.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
   
    require_once "conn.php";
    require_once "validate.php";
   
    $name = validate($_POST['name']);
    $email = validate($_POST['email']);
    $password = validate($_POST['password']);
   
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$name', '$email', '" . md5($password) . "')";
   
    if(!$conn->query($sql)){
        echo "failure";
    }else{
        echo "success";   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You are getting failure response  means there is nothing  wrong in the request. Please share the source code of regiser.php so that we can figure out whats wrong with it

Comment: Hi @NiranjanNlc, i don't know how to post code in the comment so i added code of register.php in my question. please check it thank you

Comment: seems like $conn has another name in conn.php , please check it . It should be same